# How to tag an XML DateTime attribute with XmlDateTimeSerializationMode?

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization

Is there any way I can define how a DateTime should be serialized/deserialized using something similar to the XmlAttribute tag?  In the past I would make the field a string and then do something like this in the constructor:

```
this.DateField = XmlConvert.ToString(passedObject.Date, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
```

However, I'd like to actually have the field be a DateTime and somehow tag that it should be serialized as UTC:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()] // XmlDateTimeSerializationMode tag here?
public DateTime DateField;
```

How would I do that?

Comment: I had a problem with dates not being serialised as Zulu (UTC) and it was because the dates were _NOT_ UTC, even though I thought they were. Check you code again! You've missed some needed SpecifyKind(...,...UTC) calls. (Just a note for the next person who can't get Z to be tacked onto the end of their XML serialised dates.)

Comment: @Mark Hurd Just to clarify. If I am using the *XmlSerializer* to deserialize XML and within the XML the *xs:dateTime* values have "Z" appended to them, then my *DateTime* properties will have their *DateTime.Kind* properties set to *DateTimeKind.Utc.* Is this correct?

Comment: @RickRoth I'd hope so, but I don't know -- our application only used it for serialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do it via attributes, as your crossing the line from serializing your data as it is, to transforming it and then serializing.

You could perhaps get the same result by changing the way you represent the data, by adding a UTC protected property, i.e:

```
public DateTime DateField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("DateField")]
protected DateTime UtcDateField
{
    get
    {
        //Convert DateField to UTC
    }

    set
    {
        DateField = //Convert value from UTC
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  I actually ended up having to add an XmlIgnore attribute to the real DateField or else it would serialize it as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to inherit the `IXmlSerializable` interface and handle all the reading and writing of your serialization manually. It's not as succinct or automatic as attributes but it will give you the control you need and I think it's easier to understand than creating special formatted fields just for the serialization process.